# Return a group of <td> cells

Tags: reactjs

I'm mapping through my attendance array of objects and trying to return `<td></td>` cells when attendance records exist and empty `<td></td>` cells when no attendance records exist. I'm currently only able to return `<td></td>` cells if attendance records exist. How can I do I return empty `<td></td>` cells?

Path: `file.jsx`

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="mt-3">
      <Table hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="border-top-0 pt-0">Absent</th>
            <th className="border-top-0 pt-0">Present</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.studentUserProfiles.map(studentUserProfile => (
            <tr key={studentUserProfile._id}>
              {this.props.attendances.map((attendance) => {
                if (attendance.studentUserProfileId === studentUserProfile._id) {
                  return (
                    <React.Fragment key={attendance._id}>
                      <td>{attendance.absentRollCallTeacherUserId ? 'True' : null}</td>
                      <td>{studentUserProfile.presentRollCallTeacherUserId ? 'True' : null}</td>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  );
                }
              })}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: when this.props.attendances is empty ?

Comment: If there are no attendance records to loop through for that specific profile then I need to return `<React.Fragment>
                      <td />                      <td />
                    </React.Fragment>` to render the table correctly.

Comment: If there are no attendance records(this.props.attendance.length == 0)   how will you get attendance._id ?

Comment: Ok ! just saw the updated comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you out

```js
{this.props.studentUserProfiles.map(studentUserProfile => (
    <tr key={studentUserProfile._id}>
    {this.props.attendances.find(attend => studentUserProfile._id === attend.id) ? this.props.attendances.map((attendance) => {
        if (attendance.studentUserProfileId === studentUserProfile._id) {
            return (
                <React.Fragment key={attendance._id}>
                <td>{attendance.absentRollCallTeacherUserId ? 'True' : null}</td>
                <td>{studentUserProfile.presentRollCallTeacherUserId ? 'True' : null}</td>
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    }) : (
        <React.Fragment>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </React.Fragment>
    )}
    </tr>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the length of the `this.props.attendance` before the loop starts and return the required tags using JSX.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="mt-3">
        <Table hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="border-top-0 pt-0">Absent</th>
              <th className="border-top-0 pt-0">Present</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.studentUserProfiles.map(studentUserProfile => (
              <tr key={studentUserProfile._id}>
              { this.props.attendance.length > 0 &&
                    <React.Fragment>
                     {this.props.attendances.map((attendance) => {
                         return (
                            <React.Fragment key={attendance._id}>
                                {attendance.studentUserProfileId == studentUserProfile._id &&
                                    <td>{attendance.absentRollCallTeacherUserId ? 'True' : null}</td>
                                    <td>{studentUserProfile.presentRollCallTeacherUserId ? 'True' : null}</td>
                                }
                                {attendance.studentUserProfileId != studentUserProfile._id &&
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                }
                            </React.Fragment>
                            );
                    })}
                </React.Fragment>
              }

              { this.props.attendance.length == 0 &&
                <React.Fragment >
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
               </React.Fragment>
              }

              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry that's not correct. I think I mislead you. If I have 30 user profiles and 1 attendance record then `if (attendance.studentUserProfileId === student user profile._id)` only return true 1 time. I need to return `<React.Fragment> <td /> <td /> </React.Fragment>` the other 29 times.